# How to terminate a function without 'Output argument "varargout" not assigned 'error?

Tags: matlab, return

I have a function with a variable number of arguments and outputs, and I want it to exit at a certain point if there is an additional argument:

```
function [out, varargout] = myfunction(a,varargin)

    % do stuff
    out = 1;

    if nargin > 1
       return
    end

    % do extra stuff if there is no additional argument
    varargout{1} = 'optional output';

end
```

I get the error

```
Output argument "varargout" not assigned during call to "C:\...\myfunction"
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
function varargout = my_function(a,varargin)

    % do stuff
    varargout{1} = 1;

    if nargin > 1
        if nargout > 1
            varargout(2:nargout) = {[]};
        end
       return
    end

    % do extra stuff if there is no additional argument
    varargout{2} = 'optional output';

end
```

Test:

```
[a b] = my_function(2)
a =
     1
b =
optional output

[a b] = my_function(2,3)
a =
     1
b =
     []
```

The problem is, you can't call a function with more outputs than it creates. Therefore, calling you original function `a = my_function(2,3)` would work fine, while `[a b] = my_function(2,3)` will cause an error.

Thus you have (at least) two alternatives:

1. Make sure the number of output and input variables match every time you execute the function.
2. Do as I did above.